# How to measure disk-performance under Windows?

Tags: performance, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to find out why my application is very slow on a certain machine (runs fine everywhere else).
I think i have traced the performance-problems to hard-disk reads and writes and i think it's simply the very slow disk.

What tool could i use to measure hd read and write performance under Windows 2003 in a non-destructive way (the partitions on the drives have to remain intact)?

Answer (score 279):

There is a built-in disk performance checker in Windows called `winsat`:

`winsat disk -drive g`

(Run `winsat` with Administrator privileges; `g` is the `G:` drive in this example)

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsat/using-winsat

e.g:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>winsat disk -drive g
Windows System Assessment Tool
> Running: Feature Enumeration ''
> Run Time 00:00:00.00
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive g -ran -read'
> Run Time 00:00:04.17
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive g -seq -read'
> Run Time 00:00:08.64
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive g -seq -write'
> Run Time 00:00:17.47
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive g -flush -seq'
> Run Time 00:00:03.53
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive g -flush -ran'
> Run Time 00:00:04.16
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       21.05 MB/s          6.0
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   38.29 MB/s          4.9
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  39.67 MB/s          4.9
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     1.324 ms          7.4
> Latency: 95th Percentile                     2.585 ms          7.3
> Latency: Maximum                             26.977 ms          7.9
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         1.299 ms          8.1
> Total Run Time 00:00:39.41
```

By default it doesn't test Random Write speed though, so you could check random 16.0 write with: `winsat disk -write -ran -drive c` for example.

Comment: Finally a solution which is a) build in b) command line - Thanks a lot.
To use it on a `2012 Server Core OS` I had co copy the files `winsat.exe, d3d11.dll, dxgi.dll, d3d10.dll, d3d10_1.dll, d3d10_1core.dll, d3d10core.dll`  from a windows 8 computer.

Comment: You have to run the command prompt as an administrator, otherwise it pops a new command prompt and disappears as soon as it's finished, taking the results with it.

Comment: Note that `winsat` is new in Vista.

Comment: What does the number in 3rd column in the last rows specify? The link also doesn't provide info in this respect. Any idea?

Comment: @mtk It looks like the WinSAT score assigned to the result. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Assessment_Tool

Comment: Any info on how to benchmark these numbers? How can I know if my stats are slow or not?

Comment: @aaaidan  Well, the 3rd column is the WinSAT Score which is "the WEI scores on a scale from 1.0 to 5.9 for Windows Vista,[3] 7.9 for Windows 7,[4] and 9.9 for Windows 8 and Windows 10.[5]"

Comment: Unfortunately does not support software RAID.

Answer (score 23):

HD Tach has been end of lifed.  HD Tune appears to be equivalent: http://www.hdtune.com/

[image: HD Tune screenshot]

Comment: The link is dead and there's now a [HD Tach End of Life Announcement](http://www.simplisoftware.com/) at their website saying it's no longer supported.

Comment: the free version of HD Tune 2.55 does not allow to benchmark disk write:(

Answer (score 12):

For those who might be looking for something capable of testing SQL type scenarios there's [Diskspd.exe](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223) which has superseded SQLIO.

Comment: That link is gone, DiskSpd is mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure-stack/hci/manage/diskspd-overview

Answer (score 10):

[ATTO Disk Benchmark](http://www.attotech.com/disk-benchmark/) is freeware and does not require installation.

[image]

Comment: As of 2022 requires both to fill a form and also installation... :|

Answer (score 9):

You can use Perfmon to gather physical disk based counters, such as:

- Physical Disk (instance)\Disk
  Transfers/sec counter for each
  physical disk
- Physical Disk(instance)\% Idle Time
- Avg. Disk Queue Length

Or download [PAL](http://www.codeplex.com/PAL) (very useful monitoring tool) and use the built-in template targeting the OS.

Answer (score 6):

[IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/) will do this.  It can do non-destructive testing by writing to its own files within the partitions.

Comment: Iometer sucks for the casual user.  Requires an installer (wth for) tries to open friggen sockets and the UI is your typical OSS ui--ugly, way more complex than necessary, and ultimately confusing to anybody that doesn't RTFM.

Comment: The latest version 1.1.0 doesn't run in XP, version 2006.07.27 does.

Comment: I must admit the UI is far from being user-friendly. It still gets the job done and, unlike most other benchmarking tools, measures latency.

Comment: It also saves results in CSV; if you select the same file again, it appends to it - quite nice for comparison, graphing etc.

Comment: Its force is distributed/remote benchmarking over an arbitrary setup (the utility was originally written by Intel engineers for internal use), though this is hardly ever needed in casual use.

Answer (score 5):

The performance counters in windows can show you transfer-speeds, current disk queue etc in order to trace the actual bottleneck on the machine when your app is running.

Look at Performance Object: Physical Disk

And look especially at the queue-counters. A disk can be very fast ad sequential reads, but as soon as it tries to access the disk simultaneously the queue might peak and give you horrible performance.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is a tool, which is used by Microsoft engineers to test hard drive performance (information taken from the tool project's github readme file): https://github.com/microsoft/diskspd. Although not sure if it's compatible with Windows 2003

A nice thing about it is that it can measure IOPS performance (e.g. it's possible to compare your VM with Azure instance IO performance specifications).

Example usage:

```
diskspd.exe -c10G -d30 -b4K -h -o32 -t4 -r -w100 tempfile.dat
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try with Harddisk benchmark programs:
http://www.hdtune.com/
http://www.passmark.com/products/pt_advdisk.htm

Answer (score 0):

CrystalDiskMark is for that - https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/

It shows read and write speeds - linear and access time, threaded.

[image: Example]