# How to use winsat on network share to measure disk-performance under Windows?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I found [this post](https://superuser.com/a/735081/1027789) about how to use `winsat` to measure disk performance on Windows. But if i mount a network share on drive letter `x` `winsat disk -drive x` returns `Unable to open the drive or device`.

I tried to run in regular powershell (since `winsat` must be run as administrator but administrator shell can't see mounted network shares) using `runas /user:myadminname "winsat disk -drive x"` but after authenticating i get error that the requested operation requires elevation even though `myadminname` is a admin user.

I thought about using the [idea from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777229) but I don't know the side affects for other users on the system and i don't want to remap a already mounted network drive.

Is there a way to use `winsat` to measure network mounted disk performance?

Comment: have you tried to run `winsat disk -drive MappedDriveLetter` on your system against any mapped drive? [1] there is no point in running that test on a drive that is mapped across the network. [2] i can't get that test to run on ANY mapped drive. the result is `Error: Failed to properly assess the disk.`

Comment: These tools are used to test the full spindle. This is a logical vs physical thing. These tools are for the physical drive only. A mapped drive is not a drive. A mapped share name is not a drive. It's a pointer. If you are using real storage devices in your infrastructure, then you are only getting a slice of that drive, again, not a real drive. Thus tools, like you are using, should fail (on network drives, file shares, etc.,) by design. No network admin, in their right mind, would never allow such scans/tests.

Answer (score 0):

As per the MS Docs. You only have 4 assessment options with this tool:

> Using WinSAT
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsat/using-winsat
>
> Initiating an assessment
>
> After Windows 8.1 you can initiate formal and ad hoc assessments of
> the computer. A formal assessment assesses the following subcomponents
> of the computer:

- CPU
- Memory
- ***Primary disk***
- Video card